# Fabric asks for password even though I can SSH using credential

Tags: python, django, ssh, fabric

I'm having an odd problem while deploying a Django site using Fabric. I've configured two servers to use key files for login. I can SSH into both without a password. I can run fab on one correctly,

```
$ fab live pull
[mysite.com] Executing task 'pull'
[mysite.com] run: test -d proj
[mysite.com] run: test -d proj/.git
[mysite.com] run: git pull origin master
...
```

while the other server asks for a password:

```
$ fab staging pull
[dev.mysite.com] Executing task 'pull'
[dev.mysite.com] run: test -d proj
[dev.mysite.com] Login password:
```

The fabfile is set up pretty explicitly

```
def staging():
    env.hosts = ['dev.mysite.com']
    env.user = 'bamboo'
    env.key_filename = '~/.ssh/id_dsa_bamboo'
```

And running ssh directly from the command line works

```
$ ssh bamboo@dev.mysite.com -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa_bamboo
Last login: Wed Apr 11 06:24:28 2012 from xxx.xxx.xx.xx
[bamboo@dev ~]$
```

I also tried setting `env.use_ssh_config = True` and running with `~/.ssh/config` set to

```
Host dev.mysite.com                                                                           
    User bamboo                                                                              
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa_bamboo                                                        
    ForwardAgent yes
```

Any ideas what could be going on? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Very similar here. I've could run all my tasks successfully yesterday and even today but suddenly fabric starts asking me for password.

Comment: Can anyone list possible cause for this please

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can add:

```
ssh.util.log_to_file("paramiko.log", 10)
```

To the top of your fabfile, after the imports, to get more detailed information about the authorization process.

Comment: Great, thanks for this. Pointed to me that paramiko doesn't support keys of type `ssh-ed25519`. Second gotcha is that you'll also need to ensure the remote server presents a `rsa` key as well as providing one as an `identity file`

Answer (score 10):

For me, I had to reset SSH agent identities with:

`ssh-add -D`

Then add my key back with:

`ssh-add -K keyname`

Careful, this will delete all identities from SSH agent.

Comment: `ssh-add` was sufficient for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had to update fabric (probably after osx update):

```
sudo pip install --upgrade fabric
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was unable to see anything helpful in the log files. I was able to connect, however, after first connecting to the server using `ssh` and enabling ssh-agent forwarding:

`ssh -A <user>@<host>`

Then I ran `fab` and was connected without being asked for a password as expected.